# Javascript string not being set

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
  contractToobar(): void {
      let extraItemsElements = document.getElementsByClassName('toolbar-open');
      if (extraItemsElements && extraItemsElements.length > 0) {
        for (let i: number = 0; i < extraItemsElements.length; i++) {
          extraItemsElements[i].className = 'xxx';
          console.log('after: ', extraItemsElements[i].className);
        }
      }
  }
```

I am trying to set the `extraItemsElements[i].className`. However, the code outputs the following:

> ```
> after:  toolbar toolbar-md toolbar-open toolbar-open toolbar-open toolbar-open
> ```

I would expect the value to be `'xxx'`:

i.e. `className` is not being set to the value of `xxx`.

Any advise appreciated.

UPDATE

If I try the following:

```
  contractToobar(): void {
    let replacements: string[] = [];
    let extraItemsElements = document.getElementsByClassName('toolbar-open');
    if (extraItemsElements && extraItemsElements.length > 0) {
      for (let i: number = 0; i < extraItemsElements.length; i++) {
        let s: string = this.replaceAll(extraItemsElements[i].className, ' toolbar-open', '');
        replacements[1] = s;
      }
    }
    for (let i: number = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
      extraItemsElements[i].className = replacements[i];
      console.log('after: ', extraItemsElements[i].className);
    }
  }

  replaceAll(str, find, replace): string {
    let returnValue: string = str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
    return returnValue;
  }
```

I get:

> Cannot set property 'className' of undefined

Comment: What does `this.replaceAll()` do? The error is most likely there (and in the fact, that you have `toolbar-open` more than once in the class list).

Comment: Thanks. I have simplified the code to not call the replaceAll function, and rather just set the className to 'xxx'. But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` collection is live, when you change a class for one of its items, it is removed from the collection.

Comment: Thanks @georg. Does that mean I must update the className outside the loop?

Comment: Yes, that, or convert the collection to an array first, or use `querySelectorAll` which isn't live.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `replaceAll` does, it should look like

```js
function replaceAll(reg,input,replace) {
 return input.replace(reg, function(match){
  return replace
 })
}

var r = replaceAll(/ toolbar-open/g, 'toolbar toolbar-md toolbar-open toolbar-open toolbar-open toolbar-open', '')

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my replaceAll function works fine. I cannot seem to set the clasName though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from georg, the following works:

```
  contractToobar(): void {
    let replacements: string[] = [];
    let extraItemsElements = document.getElementsByClassName('toolbar-open');
    if (extraItemsElements && extraItemsElements.length > 0) {
      for (let i: number = 0; i < extraItemsElements.length; i++) {
        let s: string = this.replaceAll(extraItemsElements[i].className, ' toolbar-open', '');
        replacements[1] = s;
      }
    }
    for (let i: number = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
      if (extraItemsElements && extraItemsElements[i] && extraItemsElements[i].className) {
        extraItemsElements[i].className = replacements[i];
      }
    }
  }

  replaceAll(str, find, replace): string {
    let returnValue: string = str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
    return returnValue;
  }``
```